# installing/uninstalling software from Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

we are a sports club running **Windows Server 2012 R2**. I am stuck with this below message on the Server while installing/uninstalling any software...
"**Another program is being installed. Please wait until that installation is complete, and then try to install the software again**"

I am searching online but no luck, any idea or help with how we can resolve this issue. Please advise.

Thank you
Inayat

Comment: Restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no other programs being installed or un-installed at the moment.

If nothing is busy installing, try restarting the computer as stated by @michael-hampton. That should clear out any unfinished installation that may be running in the background